# Can you use IIS 7.5 filtering for AlwaysAllowURLs with a wildcard or pattern?

Tags: web-services, iis

Have any of you see how to do the Always Allowed URLs  in IIS filtering/request settings with a wildcard? So you can match a pattern?

I need to filter request, but our REST Web Services follow the name/action/parameter/ID pattern and do not have specific file extensions to list as "allowed". So I need to list URLs but we have a lot. :( I would love to use a URL pattern like "/API/WSPROJECT/*" and say "allow all URLs like this.

Is that possible and how in IIS 7.5 on Win2K8 or higher? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I just posted this as https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/iis-docs/issues/938 - hopefully they could document this better or come up with alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of URL Rewrite module, you can safely migrate your block/allow rules to URL rewrite rules, which then gives you more flexibility on URL patterns and response types.